# Bind access to REACT app to specific end device

Tags: reactjs

It is possible to bind the access to a REACT app to a specific end device / machine?

The REACT app is running in the sandbox of the browser and so the access to the client machine is quiet limited. What are possible scenarios to restrict the access to the app to specific machines? Is it possible to use the hostname of the machine to identify the machine?

- Configure the webserver it self? We are using ngnix and this is unfortunatly limited in using the client hostname for garant or restrict access.
- Something with cookies which are deployed manually on the client machine?
- ...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: VPN between host and client

Comment: To be more precice: Client and server are in a secured network. For me it is important that the adress of the REACT app is not reachable from an other client machine.

Comment: not familiar with nginx, so can't advise on it. do you have a backend to filter out requests?

Comment: The backend is an independed system. Frontend and backend are communication over mqtt (there are other reasons for doing this). So for the backend the frontend is more or less anonymous. I think the easiest way is to find a solution to prevent the access on the frontend side. This would be quiet easy if JS could read the hostname of the client. But for "sandboxreasons" this is not possible I think.